# Q: User termination of a script leads to loss of logs?

Tags: robotframework

I've been trying to terminate my scripts but I've found that I usually lose these logs and I don't know why. Specifically they are the .xml, .log, and .report files that are produced after the running of a script. Is there someway I can ensure that the logs aren't deleted?

Comment: How is the script terminated?

Comment: I'm using `pybot test_script_name.robot` over terminal

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. That tells me how you start it. How are you terminating it? A single control-c should stop it while still allowing it to create the logs and reports.

Comment: Ah yes you are right sorry about that. Yes I am terminating it with Ctrl C but logs or reports are not created at times.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are pressing CTRL+C Twice, making it force exit from test run. If you press once, it will create logs.
[image]